# Why is as.Date slow on a character vector?

Tags: r, data.table

I started using data.table package in R to boost performance of my code. I am using the following code:

```
sp500 <- read.csv('../rawdata/GMTSP.csv')
days <- c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")

# Using data.table to get the things much much faster
sp500 <- data.table(sp500, key="Date")
sp500 <- sp500[,Date:=as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")]
sp500 <- sp500[,Weekday:=factor(weekdays(sp500[,Date]), levels=days, ordered=T)]
sp500 <- sp500[,Year:=(as.POSIXlt(Date)$year+1900)]
sp500 <- sp500[,Month:=(as.POSIXlt(Date)$mon+1)]
```

I noticed that the conversion done by as.Date function is very slow, when compared to other functions that create weekdays, etc. Why is that? Is there a better/faster solution, how to convert into date-format? (If you would ask whether I really need the date format, probably yes, because then use ggplot2 to make plots, which work like a charm with this type of data.)

To be more precise

```
> system.time(sp500 <- sp500[,Date:=as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")])
   user  system elapsed 
 92.603   0.289  93.014 
> system.time(sp500 <- sp500[,Weekday:=factor(weekdays(sp500[,Date]), levels=days, ordered=T)])
   user  system elapsed 
  1.938   0.062   2.001 
> system.time(sp500 <- sp500[,Year:=(as.POSIXlt(Date)$year+1900)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.304   0.001   0.305
```

On MacAir i5 with slightly less then 3000000 observations.

Comment: It's rather strange that it should very much slower. It should be doing the equivalent of: dPl <- as.POSIXlt; with( paste(mon, mdate, year, sep="/")

Comment: Did you look at the results of the conversion?

Comment: Yes, they are fine, totally. I actually have char that is formatted like mm/dd/yyyy, so it works fine.

Comment: I know this is a bit dated but let me just point to this link which might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898318/convert-character-to-date-quickly-in-r#12898544

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think it's just that `as.Date` converts `character` to `Date` via `POSIXlt`, using `strptime`. And `strptime` is very slow, I believe.

To trace it through yourself, type `as.Date`, then `methods(as.Date)`, then look at the `character` method.

```
> as.Date
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("as.Date")
<bytecode: 0x2cf4b20>
<environment: namespace:base>

> methods(as.Date)
[1] as.Date.character as.Date.date      as.Date.dates     as.Date.default  
[5] as.Date.factor    as.Date.IDate*    as.Date.numeric   as.Date.POSIXct  
[9] as.Date.POSIXlt  
   Non-visible functions are asterisked

> as.Date.character
function (x, format = "", ...) 
{
    charToDate <- function(x) {
        xx <- x[1L]
        if (is.na(xx)) {
            j <- 1L
            while (is.na(xx) && (j <- j + 1L) <= length(x)) xx <- x[j]
            if (is.na(xx)) 
                f <- "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
        if (is.na(xx) || !is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d", 
            tz = "GMT")) || !is.na(strptime(xx, f <- "%Y/%m/%d", 
            tz = "GMT"))) 
            return(strptime(x, f))
        stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
    }
    res <- if (missing(format)) 
        charToDate(x)
    else strptime(x, format, tz = "GMT")       ####  slow part, I think  ####
    as.Date(res)
}
<bytecode: 0x2cf6da0>
<environment: namespace:base>
>
```

Why is `as.POSIXlt(Date)$year+1900` relatively fast?  Again, trace it through :

```
> as.POSIXct
function (x, tz = "", ...) 
UseMethod("as.POSIXct")
<bytecode: 0x2936de8>
<environment: namespace:base>

> methods(as.POSIXct)
[1] as.POSIXct.date    as.POSIXct.Date    as.POSIXct.dates   as.POSIXct.default
[5] as.POSIXct.IDate*  as.POSIXct.ITime*  as.POSIXct.numeric as.POSIXct.POSIXlt
   Non-visible functions are asterisked

> as.POSIXlt.Date
function (x, ...) 
{
    y <- .Internal(Date2POSIXlt(x))
    names(y$year) <- names(x)
    y
}
<bytecode: 0x395e328>
<environment: namespace:base>
>
```

Intrigued, let's dig into Date2POSIXlt. For this bit we need to grep main/src to know which .c file to look at.

```
~/R/Rtrunk/src/main$ grep Date2POSIXlt *
names.c:{"Date2POSIXlt",do_D2POSIXlt,   0,  11, 1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
$
```

Now we know we need to look for D2POSIXlt :

```
~/R/Rtrunk/src/main$ grep D2POSIXlt *
datetime.c:SEXP attribute_hidden do_D2POSIXlt(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
names.c:{"Date2POSIXlt",do_D2POSIXlt,   0,  11, 1,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
$
```

Oh, we could have guessed datetime.c. Anyway, so looking at latest live copy :

[datetime.c](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/datetime.c)

Search in there for `D2POSIXlt` and you'll see how simple it is to go from Date (numeric) to POSIXlt. You'll also see how POSIXlt is one real vector (8 bytes) plus seven integer vectors (4 bytes each). That's 40 bytes, per date!

So the crux of the issue (I think) is why `strptime` is so slow, and maybe that can be improved in R. Or just avoid `POSIXlt`, either directly or indirectly.

---

Here's a reproducible example using the number of items stated in question (3,000,000) :

```
> Range = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2012-01-01"),by="days")
> Date = format(sample(Range,3000000,replace=TRUE),"%m/%d/%Y")
> system.time(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
   user  system elapsed 
 21.681   0.060  21.760 
> system.time(strptime(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
   user  system elapsed 
 29.594   8.633  38.270 
> system.time(strptime(Date, "%m/%d/%Y", tz="GMT"))
   user  system elapsed 
 19.785   0.000  19.802
```

Passing `tz` appears to speed up `strptime`, which `as.Date.character` does. So maybe it depends on your locale. But `strptime` appears to be the culprit, not `data.table`. Perhaps rerun this example and see if it takes 90 seconds for you on your machine?

Comment: system.time(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) takes 48.594s of elapsed time.

Answer (score 32):

As others mentioned, `strptime` (converting from character to POSIXlt) is the bottleneck here. Another simple solution uses the `lubridate` package and its `fast_strptime` method instead.

Here's what it looks like on my data:

```
> tables()
     NAME      NROW  MB COLS                                     
[1,] pp   3,718,339 126 session_id,date,user_id,path,num_sessions
     KEY         
[1,] user_id,date
Total: 126MB

> pp[, 2]
               date
      1: 2013-09-25
      2: 2013-09-25
      3: 2013-09-25
      4: 2013-09-25
      5: 2013-09-25
     ---           
3718335: 2013-09-25
3718336: 2013-09-25
3718337: 2013-09-25
3718338: 2013-10-11
3718339: 2013-10-11

> system.time(pp[, date := as.Date(fast_strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.315   0.026   0.344
```

For comparison:

```
> system.time(pp[, date := as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d")])
   user  system elapsed 
108.193   0.399 108.844
```

That's ~316 times faster!

Comment: This is tip was awesome. I hope the data.table folks incorporate such a speed up. I've now made "fast" date/time functions and put them in most of my packages e.g. fast.as.IDate <- function(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d", ...) data.table::as.IDate(lubridate::fast_strptime(x, format = format, ...))

Comment: `as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(datevector,orders="ymd"))` was about twice as fast as this in my benchmark, but `u=unique(datevector);as.Date(u)[match(datevector,u)]` was about 4 times faster.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the suggestions. I solved it by writing the Gaussian algorithm for the dates myself and got far better results, see below.

```
getWeekDay <- function(year, month, day) {
  # Implementation of the Gaussian algorithm to get weekday 0 - Sunday, ... , 7 - Saturday
  Y <- year
  Y[month<3] <- (Y[month<3] - 1)

  d <- day
  m <- ((month + 9)%%12) + 1
  c <- floor(Y/100)
  y <- Y-c*100
  dayofweek <- (d + floor(2.6*m - 0.2) + y + floor(y/4) + floor(c/4) - 2*c) %% 7
  return(dayofweek)
}

sp500 <- read.csv('../rawdata/GMTSP.csv')
days <- c("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")

# Using data.table to get the things much much faster
sp500 <- data.table(sp500, key="Date")
sp500 <- sp500[,Month:=as.integer(substr(Date,1,2))]
sp500 <- sp500[,Day:=as.integer(substr(Date,4,5))]
sp500 <- sp500[,Year:=as.integer(substr(Date,7,10))]
#sp500 <- sp500[,Date:=as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")]
#sp500 <- sp500[,Weekday:=factor(weekdays(sp500[,Date]), levels=days, ordered=T)]
sp500 <- sp500[,Weekday:=factor(getWeekDay(Year, Month, Day))]
levels(sp500$Weekday) <- days
```

Running the whole block above gives (including reading the date from csv)... Data.table is truly impressive.

```
user  system elapsed 
 19.074   0.803  20.284
```

Timing of the conversion itself is 3.49 elapsed.

Comment: Glad you're happy, but 20s for this still seems relatively slow. Here are a few related questions [search for +strptime +slow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%2Bstrptime+%2Bslow) which might help.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle The timing of the function itself is 3.5 secs, which seems fine to me. The most time of the 20s are consumed by reading the data from the disk. (I updated above.)

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit. That's better.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but I think this tiny trick it might be useful. If you have multiple rows with the same date, you can do

`data[, date := as.Date(date[1]), by = date]`

It's much faster since it only processes each date once (in my dataset of 40 million rows it goes from 25 seconds to 0.5 seconds).

Comment: To expand on why this is faster, because I was confused: Suppose you have information for the sale of a million items, and you tracked the number of sales for 1 week. You would have 7 million rows. Without the "by" part, it would compute the weekday for a row, then move onto the next and compute, then next, etc. Using the "by" part, it first groups your rows into specific days (so 7 days) and then only computes the weekday for each of those 7 days (7 computations instead of 7 million). Then it takes the result and assigns it as a new column for each respective group

Comment: I understand the idea but I do not understand the code. What is `data` and `date`? A working example would be nice.

Comment: `data` is any data.table that has a column called `date`.

Answer (score 2):

I originally thought: "The argument to as.Date above does not have the format specified."

I now think: I assumed the Date value that you were keying on was in a standard format. I guess not. So you are doing two processes. You are reformatting from character to Date format and you are re-sorting based on the new values which have a completely different collation sequence.

Comment: Re-sorting? What does it mean exactly?

Comment: In order to set a key you need to create an index... a hash table I think ... that lets you do the rapid look-ups that data.table provides. If you change the values of the key, I assume you need to redo the creation of the look-up table.

Comment: Aha, but then I guess it does it with every changed value (which seems contra-intuitive to me, I actually think that the hash table only updates after the update, correct me if I am wrong). The conversion from data.frame to data.table goes fast > system.time(sp500 <- data.table(sp500, key="Date"))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.168   0.024   0.192

Comment: Maybe it is thrashing through the re-keying process unnecessarily. You could test by removing the key, converting and re-establishing the key. Whether there is a better way is a Matthew Dowle level question.

Comment: @tomaskrehlik, DWin, it's not a `data.table` thing at all. Assigning to a key column drops the key; it isn't maintained/rebuilt. Definitely worth confirming by just timing `as.Date(sp500$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")` outside `data.table`, though, as I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I guess we need a real example to bang our hammers on.

Comment: @DWin No problem, yes indeed. Must be easier way that OP's new answer? R users shouldn't need to jump through these hoops! Btw, following up on your earlier comment above, `setkey` merely orders the data by those columns and then adds an attribute `"sorted"` holding the column names it's sorted by. Lookup is then binary search. Albeit a multi column binary search with bells and whistles like `roll=TRUE`. Nothing more to it than that, though. No hash table used. It's mainly about _ordered_ joins.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a little (one-function) package that is on CRAN called calcUnique that should speed this up quite a bit.  Adapting from Matt Dowle ...

```
> Range = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2012-01-01"), by = "days")
> Date = format(sample(Range, 3000000, replace = TRUE), "%m/%d/%Y")
> system.time(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.160   0.000   1.157 
> system.time(strptime(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.628   2.385   5.008 
> system.time(strptime(Date, "%m/%d/%Y", tz = "GMT"))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.849   0.001   0.851 
> system.time(calcUnique::calcUnique(Date, strptime, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.244   0.000   0.244 
> system.time(calcUnique::calcUnique(Date, strptime, format = "%m/%d/%Y", tz = "GMT"))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.173   0.000   0.172 
>
```