# convert character to date *quickly* in R

Tags: r, date, character, posix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is as.Date slow on a character vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786335/why-is-as-date-slow-on-a-character-vector)

I have a large `data.frame` (roughly 60 mil observations) that I read from a database using `RMySQL`. The dates are brought in as characters (there doesn't seem to be a way to change this) and so I use `as.Date` to convert things to date.  However, this takes an extremely long time witih so many observations.  Is there anything one can do to make this faster?

Comment: It might be faster to dump the whole table to a CSV, and then use `scan` to pull in the table with the right column classes. It sounds cheesy, but it is fast.

Comment: @nograpes: do you know off the top of your head if `read.csv` does the same conversion? it might not make a difference.

Comment: @BenBolker: actually took a look at that but it doesn't seem like there was a solution. the OP was trying to figure out if it was a `data.table` problem.. and it was not. did i miss something in there?

Comment: @Alex: Good point. I checked and it is the same thing. It won't make a difference.

Comment: @Alex: I think you did miss something, if I read the answers correctly. Matthew Dowle's answer traced the problem back to `strptime`, and the OP's answer to his own question showed how he wrote some code that reduced the conversion time by a factor of about 10 ...

Comment: @BenBolker: great! thanks for pointing this out, let me look again

Comment: @Alex I am the OP from the other question. My general advice (I have been struggling with the problem for some time) with so much data is to parse the string by `stringr` to separate integer fields and if you want to use the Date format for specific needed purposes such as axes in plots, you just convert the subset that you plot, which doesn't hurt that much in terms of comp time. Date seems hugely inefficient for big data purposes...

Comment: @tomaskrehlik: thanks very much, appreciated advice. just fyi, the answer provided below is quite good.. it took about 20 seconds or so for 60 million observations

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simon Urbanek's [fasttime](http://rforge.net/fasttime) library is *very* fast for a subset of parseable datetimes:

```
R> now <- Sys.time()
R> now
[1] "2012-10-15 10:07:28.981 CDT"
R> fasttime::fastPOSIXct(format(now))
[1] "2012-10-15 05:07:28.980 CDT"
R> as.Date(fasttime::fastPOSIXct(format(now)))
[1] "2012-10-15"
R>
```

However, it only parse ISO formats and assume UTC as timezone.

*Edit after 3 1/2 years:*  Some commenters appear to think that the fasttime package is difficult to install.  I beg to differ.  Here is (once again) use `install.r` which is just a simple wrapper using [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) (and also shipped as an example with):

```
edd@max:~$ install.r fasttime
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/fasttime_1.0-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2646 bytes
==================================================
downloaded 2646 bytes

* installing *source* package ‘fasttime’ ...
** package ‘fasttime’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
ccache gcc -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99  -c tparse.c -o tparse.o
ccache gcc -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o fasttime.so tparse.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/fasttime/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (fasttime)

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
edd@max:~$
```

As you can see, the package has zero external dependencies, one source file and builds without the slightest hitch.  We can also see that [fasttime](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=fasttime) is now on CRAN which was not the case when the answer was written.  With that, Windows and OS X binaries now do exist at that page *and the installation will be as easy as it was for me* even when you do not install from source.

Comment: Yup, it helps when `strptime()` is in fact the binding restriction, but in many other cases the adding parsing flexibility help.

Comment: Note, however, that it only works with dates > 1970!! This is a weird restriction.. must be something with POSIX??

Comment: fasttime needs updating for use with R 3.1

Comment: Is that so? The example above works for me as before. Can you document an error case in email to Simon? And if you don't mind, CC me?

Comment: I believe Michael was referring to the build. There doesn't appear to be any binary available for R 3.1.0

Comment: This is why I quit R, sigh. ...

Comment: You can't be serious.  CRAN just works.  If you're after a package not on CRAN all you need is the build tools.

Comment: @Alex, it only works for dates past 1970, as Simon is using a POSIXct variable, which is defined as seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00.000. This is in the documentation for fasttime, I believe.