# R- efficiently convert time in milliseconds to as.POSIXct with varying time zones

Tags: r, timezone, posixct

I'd like to convert multiple time values with varying time zones, currently represented as milliseconds since 01-01-1970, to a POSIXct format.

I have the following dataset:

```
times <- c(1427450400291, 1428562800616, 1418651628795, 1418651938990, 1418652348281, 1418652450161)
tzones <- c("America/Los_Angeles", "Africa/Casablanca", "Africa/Casablanca", "Africa/Casablanca", "Africa/Casablanca", "Israel Standard Time")
```

The problem is that the `as.POSIXct` method only accepts one tz value, and not a vector. Therefore, I can't call it directly. I tried using lapply and call it element by element, but it takes a long time (for longer vectors):

```
get.dates.with.timezones <- function(epoch.vec,tz.vec) {  
    res <- lapply(seq(epoch.vec),function(x){
           as.POSIXct(epoch.vec[x]/1000,origin = "1970-01-01", tz = tz.vec[x])
        })
        return(do.call(c,res))
}
```

So for only 1200 values, it takes almost a second.

```
timesX200 <- rep(times,200)
tzonesX200 <- rep(tzones,200)
system.time( get.dates.with.timezones(timesX200,tzonesX200) )
           user              system             elapsed 
0.86800000000005184 0.01999999999999602 0.88899999999921420
```

I'm a newbie with R, so I wonder if there are ways to improve the performance for this task. is there a vectorized option for this problem? Additionally, it looks like the `as.POXIXct()` method itself has some performance issues, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638545/speedup-conversion-of-2-million-rows-of-date-strings-to-posix-ct).

---------- EDIT --------

Apparentely it is impossible to hold a vector of POSIXct with varying time zones. From the POSIXct documentation:

> Using c on "POSIXlt" objects converts them to the current time zone,
>   and on "POSIXct" objects drops any "tzone" attributes (even if they
>   are all marked with the same time zone). [Source](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html)

That's too bad. I wonder if there are any alternatives for dealing with date + time + varying time zone. Would be happy to hear if there is.

Comment: I would give the time functions in the `lubridate` package a go, they are much more efficient than `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra Thanks. I looked at `lubridate` but couldn't find a method for what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found this method to be much faster. It also outputs a list which preserves the time zones created:

```
f_time <- function(x,y) as.POSIXct(x/1000, origin="1970-01-01", tz=y)
s <- split(timesX200, tzonesX200)
result <- mapply(f_time, s, names(s))
```

Your output does not retain the time-zone assignments. Check your output:

```
get.dates.with.timezones(times, tzones)
[1] "2015-03-27 06:00:00 EDT" "2015-04-09 03:00:00 EDT"
[3] "2014-12-15 08:53:48 EST" "2014-12-15 08:58:58 EST"
[5] "2014-12-15 09:05:48 EST" "2014-12-15 09:07:30 EST"
```

They are all coerced to the local time-zone.

**benchmark test**

```
times <- c(1427450400291, 1428562800616, 1418651628795, 1418651938990, 1418652348281, 1418652450161)
tzones <- c("America/Los_Angeles", "Africa/Casablanca", "Africa/Casablanca", "Africa/Casablanca", "Africa/Casablanca", "Israel")

timesX200 <- rep(times,200)
tzonesX200 <- rep(tzones,200)


get.dates.with.timezones <- function(epoch.vec,tz.vec) {  
    res <- lapply(seq(epoch.vec),function(x){
           as.POSIXct(epoch.vec[x]/1000,origin = "1970-01-01", tz = tz.vec[x])
        })
        return(do.call(c,res))
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  get = get.dates.with.timezones(timesX200, tzonesX200),
  plafort = {s <- split(timesX200, tzonesX200);mapply(f_time, s, names(s))},
  times=20L)
# Unit: microseconds
#     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq
#      get 342693.638 362465.069 378195.687 372553.491 389080.277
#  plafort    997.138   1027.731   1110.846   1107.471   1149.314
#         max neval cld
#  445539.744    20   b
#    1558.473    20  a
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any simple way to maintain a vector output? The previous function was suitable for creating a vector which is a part of a data frame. Additionally, it doesn't keep the original order.

Comment: maybe with lubridate or chron. I'll look at some ways and add to the answer