# Populate a large data frame with calculated values

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a rather large data frame (1.65 MM rows) that looks like this:

```
  date        dayofyear time humidity temp
1 2008-01-01         1  300       99  38.2
2 2008-01-01         1  302       99  38.5
3 2008-01-01         1  304       99  38.5
4 2008-01-01         1  306       99  38.6
5 2008-01-01         1  308       99  38.9
6 2008-01-01         1  310       99  39.1
....
```

I want to calculate solar noon for each row and add it as a new column to the data frame. The `suncalc::getSunlightTimes(date)` function gives me the solar noon for any given date.

If I do this:

```
solarNoons <- suncalc::getSunlightTimes(date = as.Date(dataFrame$date))
```

then (obviously) even after an hour, the command doesn't finish.

One observation -- even though there are 1.65 MM rows in the data frame, there are only around 3000 unique dates. What's the best way to approach this? Can one call `getSunlightTimes()` only 3000 times and still populate each of the 1.65 MM rows of the data frame with the values in a new column?

It's my first time posting, but long time reading and learning. Much appreciated.

Comment: use the `unique` function to isolate these unique dates to their own `data.frame`. calculate the solar noons of this minimal set. merge the result back to the original data. without a reproducible example, I can only offer this advice to help nudge you along (as well as provide some "buzzwords" to Google further)

Comment: Don't you also need to pass `lat` and `lon` co-ordinates to get "solarNoon" time? Moreover, use `keep` parameter to calculate only "solarNoon" and avoid other unwanted calculations.

Comment: Assign `df$date <- as.Date(df$date)` as early as possible, ideally right after you read it in. Strings are more unwieldy than Date objects. That way you avoid creating a temporary with 1.65m strings, 99+% of which are duplicates anyway.

Comment: You totally won't need this, but [R supports caching function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262485/options-for-caching-memoization-hashing-in-r), so again calling it 1.65m on only 3000 unique values will only result in 3000 calls. But just use dplyr::group_by(date)

Comment: Related: [Speedup conversion of 2 million rows of date strings to POSIX.ct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638545/speedup-conversion-of-2-million-rows-of-date-strings-to-posix-ct) using `fasttime` library

Comment: This is all great feedback. I've implemented it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work.  Suppose we generate a data frame of 2 million rows:

```
> N <- 2e6
> R <- data.frame(year = sample(2000:2009,N,TRUE),
+                 dayofyear = sample(365,N,TRUE),
+                 time = floor(runif(N,0,12))*100+floor(runif(N,0,60)),
+                 humidity = 99,
+                 temp = floor(runif(N,15,40)))
> R$date <- as.Date(with(R,strptime(paste(year,dayofyear),
+                                   "%Y %j", tz="GMT")))
> nrow(R)
[1] 2000000
> head(R)
  year dayofyear time humidity temp       date
1 2000       206  307       99   39 2000-07-24
2 2009       101 1019       99   16 2009-04-11
3 2004       307  547       99   21 2004-11-02
4 2003       270 1158       99   33 2003-09-27
5 2006        21  330       99   22 2006-01-21
6 2005       154  516       99   21 2005-06-03
>
```

In this case, `date` is already a `Date` column, but if yours is a character column, then:

```
> R$date <- as.Date(R$date)
```

should only take a few seconds.

Now, get a list of all the unique date values.  This should be quite fast:

```
> dates <- unique(R$date)
> print(length(dates))
[1] 3650
>
```

Now, run `getSunlightTimes` on this vector.  This only took a couple of seconds on my machine using `suncalc` version 0.4 and R version 3.4.4:

```
> times <- suncalc::getSunlightTimes(dates, lat=0, lon=0)
```

Now, generate an index vector giving the index of each date in `R$date` within the vector of unique dates `dates`:

```
> i <- match(R$date, dates)
```

Now, select rows of the `times` dataframe by this same index:

```
> solarNoons <- times[i,]
> nrow(solarNoons)
[1] 2000000
>
```

If we pick a row of R:

```
> R[1234567,]
        year dayofyear time humidity temp       date
1234567 2002        24  535       99   17 2002-01-24
```

you'll see that the corresponding row of `solarNoons` is the result for that date:

```
> solarNoons[1234567,]
                        date lat lon           solarNoon               nadir
2616.352 2002-01-24 12:00:00   0   0 2002-01-24 12:13:14 2002-01-24 00:13:14
                     sunrise              sunset          sunriseEnd
2616.352 2002-01-24 06:09:42 2002-01-24 18:16:46 2002-01-24 06:11:58
                 sunsetStart                dawn                dusk
2616.352 2002-01-24 18:14:30 2002-01-24 05:47:49 2002-01-24 18:38:39
                nauticalDawn        nauticalDusk            nightEnd
2616.352 2002-01-24 05:22:22 2002-01-24 19:04:06 2002-01-24 04:56:50
                       night       goldenHourEnd          goldenHour
2616.352 2002-01-24 19:29:38 2002-01-24 06:38:39 2002-01-24 17:47:49
>
```

If you want, you can merge the two data frames together:

```
> R2 <- cbind(R, solarNoons)
```

This all assumes that "1.65 MM" meant 1.65 million.  If you meant 1.65 million million (i.e., an American trillion), then you're going to need a bigger computer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! `unique`, `match`, `[i, ]`, and `cbind` got me home!

Answer (score 0):

**Only call the expensive function once on each distinct value of `df$date`.** Now you will only call it 3000 times instead of 1.65m times. Should be 550x faster. Also apply whatever function-specific speedup tips @RonakShah is suggesting.

```
# Assign df$date <- as.Date(df$date) as early as possible, ideally right after you read it in    
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% group_by(date) %>%
             mutate(solarNoon = suncalc::getSunlightTimes(df$date, ...))
```

Two ways to ensure you only call `suncalc::getSunlightTimes()` once on each date:

1. `group_by(date) %>% ...` pipe into your `suncalc::getSunlightTimes(df$date, ...)` call
2. [use caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262485/options-for-caching-memoization-hashing-in-r)

I'd favor way 1. since it's easy to code and teaches you good decomposition in general. Always try to structure your code to avoid calling expensive functions a million times unnecessarily.

Comment: In the severely unlikely event this is still too slow/hangs, iterate over your df in chunks of say 10000 lines or whatever.

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work on my machine. The command wouldn't finish. I too believe this should have worked.

Comment: @C.Mitty: did you follow my suggestion "In the severely unlikely event this is still too slow/hangs, iterate over your df in chunks of say 10000 lines or whatever." Try `df[1:10000,] %>% group_by(date) ...`