# convert string date to R Date FAST for all dates

Tags: r, date, posix

This has been asked several times with no clear answer: I would like to convert an R character string of the form "YYYY-mm-dd" into a `Date`. The `as.Date` function is exceedingly slow.  [convert character to date *quickly* in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898318/convert-character-to-date-quickly-in-r) provides a solution using `fasttime` that works for dates from 1970 onward.  My issue is I have dates starting from 1900 that I need to convert and there are about 100 million of them.  I have to do this frequently so the speed is important.  Are there any other solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is as.Date slow on a character vector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786335/why-is-as-date-slow-on-a-character-vector)

Comment: do you really need them to be in Date/as.Date format?

Comment: quickly means the 100 million operator should take less than a minute. and i do need them to be in `Date` format.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I don't believe this is a duplicate since I know why this is slow.. I'm looking for a solution in an R package that might exist.

Comment: I confirm it is really slow to use the Date format, and I am using data for 50 years. In my case it was ok to switch to a string and do strsplit for the queries of year,month,day in my code.

Comment: The link I provided, accepted answer, has someone who implemented their own routine to do this, which in turn would be a *potential* solution to your problem and thus was reason enough for me to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: What are you doing with your 100 million dates when you have converted them? It can't be much if the conversion is taking a significant amount of time...

Comment: @Spacedman: I use `data.table` for subsetting, computing elapsed time, rolling by date, etc.

Comment: Yes, but there's not much point speeding up a 10 minute conversion if the analyses take two hours.

Comment: the analysis does not take two hours. data.table is VERY fast.

Comment: How does fasttime compare to lubridate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can get a little speedup by using the `date` package:

```
library(date)
set.seed(21)
x <- as.character(Sys.Date()-sample(40000, 1e6, TRUE))
system.time(dDate <- as.Date(x))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    6.54    0.01    6.56 
system.time(ddate <- as.Date(as.date(x,"ymd")))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    3.42    0.22    3.64
```

You might want to look at the C code it uses and see if you can modify it to be faster for your specific situation.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem a while ago and came up with the following solution:

1. convert the string to a **factor** (if not already a factor)
2. **convert the levels** of the factor to a Date
3. **Expand** the converted levels to the solution **using the index vector** of the factor

Extending Joshua Ulrich's example, I get (with slower timings on my laptop)

```
library(date)
set.seed(21)
x <- as.character(Sys.Date()-sample(40000, 1e6, TRUE))
system.time(dDate <- as.Date(x))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    12.09   0.00   12.12 
system.time(ddate <- as.Date(as.date(x,"ymd")))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    6.97    0.04    7.05 
system.time({
    xf <- as.factor(x)
    dDate <- as.Date(levels(xf))[as.integer(xf)]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.16    0.00    1.15
```

Here, step 2 does not depend on the length of x once x is large enough and step 3 scales extremely well (simple vector indexing). The bottleneck should be step 1, which can be avoided if the data is already stored as a factor.

Comment: The output of step 3, "dDate", is not a factor. class(dDate) = Date. So, I don't understand why you do the factor conversion on the string and then perform as.Date(levels(xf)). Is it just for speeding up the conversion?

Answer (score 7):

The function `parse_date_time` from the 'lubridate' package is quite fast too:

```r
library(date)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(21)
x <- as.character(Sys.Date()-sample(40000, 1e6, TRUE))
system.time(date1 <- as.Date(x))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 12.86    0.00   12.94 
system.time(date2 <- as.Date(as.date(x,"ymd"))) # from package 'date'
#  user  system elapsed 
#  4.82    0.00    4.85 
system.time(date3 <- as.Date(parse_date_time(x,'%y-%m-%d'))) # from package 'lubridate'
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.27    0.00    0.26 
all(date1 == date2)
#  TRUE
all(date1 == date3)
#  TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider incredibly fast `anytime` library which is fine with 1970< issue. It uses the Boost date_time C++ library and provides functions `anytime()` and `anydate()` for conversions.

Comparison:

```
require(microbenchmark) #microbenchmark()
require(data.table)     #as.IDate()
require(lubridate)      #parse_date_time()
require(anytime)        #anydate()

set.seed(21)
test.dd <- as.character(as.Date("2018-05-16") - sample(40000, 1e6, TRUE)) #1 mln. random dates as character

microbenchmark(
    strptime(test.dd, "%Y-%m-%d"),                     #basic strptime
    as.IDate(test.dd, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),            #data.table
    parse_date_time(test.dd, orders = "ymd"),          #lubridate (POSIXct class)
    as.Date(parse_date_time(test.dd, orders = "ymd")), #lubridate + date class conversion
    anydate(test.dd, calcUnique=TRUE),                 #anytime library
    times = 10L, unit = "s"
)
```

Result/Output:

```
Unit: seconds
                                              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
                     strptime(test.dd, "%Y-%m-%d") 3.20226296 3.21864192 3.23682590 3.22977044 3.25419642 3.2883110    10
            as.IDate(test.dd, format = "%Y-%m-%d") 0.41928404 0.43450171 0.44044098 0.43954963 0.44784917 0.4571288    10
          parse_date_time(test.dd, orders = "ymd") 0.08309633 0.09148617 0.10280418 0.09585531 0.10695675 0.1648685    10
 as.Date(parse_date_time(test.dd, orders = "ymd")) 0.09101104 0.10380446 0.12110250 0.10821211 0.11876654 0.2009111    10
               anydate(test.dd, calcUnique = TRUE) 0.07998862 0.08125050 0.08933788 0.08442504 0.09745258 0.1032803    10
```

It is also worth to mention that:

1. `as.IDate` works that efficient only when explicitly provided with date format.
2. `parse_date_time` can't even work without explicit date format argument.
3. `anydate` can handle format automatically and it's especially efficient when dealing with varying input character date formats, which is not illustrated with this particular test case.

p.s. For working with *time series* consider `flipTime` library. It has all required tools and almost as fast as `anytime` for conversion purposes:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("Displayr/flipTime")
```

Comment: `anydate` isn't actually that fast, but it was just fast in your benchmark because you forgot to convert your test vector to character (so your input was already a date vector).

Comment: @nisetama, good point. 
Personally, I was looking for fast conversion from POSIX to Date so could miss that, however if sticking exactly to character input, `anydate` is still the fastest, just change its `calcUnique` default argument to `TRUE`:
`anytime::anydate(test.dd, calcUnique=TRUE)`.
I've update my answer accordingly (since it's valid for both input types).

Comment: I now added `anydate::anytime(v,calcUnique=T)` to my benchmark, but it was not much faster than `u=unique(v);as.Date(u)[match(v,u)]`.

Comment: @nisetama, thank you for updated benchmark. I agree `anytime::anydate` isn't that much faster when converting character input but still it is the fastest. On top it handles 1970< problem and automatically detecting date formats even when it diverse within a single vector, making it simple to use, fast and robust at the same time. Concerning `u=unique(v);as.Date(u)[match(v,u)]`, it's near top efficient, reflects a deep understanding of R vectorized operations and efficient data handling techniques, however some may find it complicated.

Answer (score 5):

A further speedup: You already work with data.table. So, create a lookup table with your dates and merge them with your data.

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

y <- seq(as.Date('1900-01-01'), Sys.Date(), by = 'day')
id.date <- data.table(id = as.character(y), date = as.Date(y), key = 'id')

set.seed(21)
x <- as.character(Sys.Date()-sample(40000, 1e6, TRUE))

system.time(date3 <- as.Date(parse_date_time(x,'%y-%m-%d'))) # from package 'lubridate'
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.15  0.00   0.15  

system.time(date4 <- id.date[setDT(list(id = x)), on='id', date])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.08  0.00   0.08

all(date3 == date4)
# TRUE
```

It's kind of a workaround, but I believe thats how data.table is intended to use. I don't know if the above mentioned time/date packages internally are based on algorithms or as well on lookup tables (hash tables).

For larger datasets, whenever there is character manipulation involved, which tend to be slow, I consider switching to lookup a reference table.

Answer (score 0):

This was slightly faster than the factor method used by Jonas Rauch:

```
> v=as.character(Sys.Date()-sample(1e4,1e6,T))
> system.time({u=unique(v);as.Date(u)[match(v,u)]})
   user  system elapsed
  0.041   0.000   0.042
```

This is fast but it only works with the `%Y-%m-%d` format, and it doesn't work with dates before 1970 as the OP found out:

```
> system.time(fasttime::fastDate(v))
   user  system elapsed
  0.021   0.000   0.021
> fasttime::fastDate("1969-01-01")
[1] NA
```

Benchmark:

```
v=as.character(Sys.Date()-sample(1e4,1e6,T))

b=microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=10,
  as.Date(v),
  fasttime::fastDate(v),
  {u=unique(v);as.Date(u)[match(v,u)]},
  {f=as.factor(v);as.Date(levels(f))[as.integer(f)]},
  {f=as.factor(v);as.Date(levels(f))[f]},
  as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(v,"ymd")),
  as.Date(lubridate::fast_strptime(v,"%Y-%m-%d")),
  strptime(v,"%Y-%m-%d"),
  anytime::anydate(v),
  anytime::anydate(v,calcUnique=T),
  data.table(x=v)[,y:=as.Date(x),by=x]$y,
  {y=seq(as.Date(min(v)),as.Date(max(v)),1);data.table(id=as.character(y),date=as.Date(y),key="id")[setDT(list(id=v)),on="id",date]},
  as.Date(date::as.date(v,"ymd"))
)

o=sort(tapply(b$time,gsub("  +"," ",b$expr),median))
writeLines(sprintf("%.2f %s",o/min(o),names(o)))
```

The output shows the median time of ten runs relative to the fastest option:

```
1.00 fasttime::fastDate(v)
2.62 anytime::anydate(v, calcUnique = T)
3.65 { u = unique(v) as.Date(u)[match(v, u)] }
4.57 { f = as.factor(v) as.Date(levels(f))[f] }
4.71 { f = as.factor(v) as.Date(levels(f))[as.integer(f)] }
6.32 as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(v, "ymd"))
7.46 as.Date(lubridate::fast_strptime(v, "%Y-%m-%d"))
11.79 { y = seq(as.Date(min(v)), as.Date(max(v)), 1) data.table(id = as.character(y), date = as.Date(y), key = "id")[setDT(list(id = v)), on = "id", date] }
19.52 data.table(x = v)[, `:=`(y, as.Date(x)), by = x]$y
40.85 as.Date(date::as.date(v, "ymd"))
56.01 anytime::anydate(v)
134.86 strptime(v, "%Y-%m-%d")
143.95 as.Date(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are between 1948 and 2075, package `grattanInflators` has good performance, around 3000 times faster than as.Date. For more general dates, you can use `fasttime`

```r
x <- rep_len(as.character(Sys.Date()-sample(4000, 1e6, TRUE)), 1e7)

bench::system_time(as.Date(x))
#> 1.27 minutes

bench::system_time(grattanInflators::fast_as_idate(x))
#> 150 ms

bench::system_time(fasttime::fastDate(x))
#> 290 ms

bench::system_time(grattanInflators::fast_as_idate(x, nThread = 10L))
#> 24 ms
```