# Faster date formatting in R?

Tags: performance, r, date, posixct

I often need to convert (long) character strings into the date class in R.  I notice that this step seems quite slow.

Example:

```
date <- c("5/31/2013 23:30", "5/31/2013 23:35", "5/31/2013 23:40", "5/31/2013 23:45", "5/31/2013 23:50", "5/31/2013 23:55")

Date <- as.POSIXct(date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

This isn't a huge problem, but I wonder if I'm overlooking an easy route to increased efficiency. Any tips for speeding this up?  Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218297/convert-string-date-to-r-date-fast-for-all-dates

Comment: There is package [fasttime](http://www.rforge.net/fasttime/), but it requires a specific format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898318/convert-character-to-date-quickly-in-r

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786335/why-is-as-date-slow-on-a-character-vector

Comment: @BenBolker: Two of those convert to `Date`, not `POSIXt`... Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13638545/271616

Comment: @BenBolker point taken, sorry for the duplicate post. Thanks for the references, and the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I wrote this before it was pointed out this is a duplicate, I'll add it as an answer anyway. Basically package `fasttime` can help you *IF* you have dates *AFTER* `1970-01-01 00:00:00` *AND* they are `GMT` *AND* they are of the format `year, month, day, hour, minute, second`. If you can rewrite your dates to this format then `fastPOSIXct` will be quick:

```
#  data
date <- c( "2013/5/31 23:30" , "2013/5/31 23:35" , "2013/5/31 23:40" , "2013/5/31 23:45" )

require(fasttime)
#  fasttime function
dates.ft <- fastPOSIXct( date , tz = "GMT" )

#  base function
dates <- as.POSIXct( date , format= "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")    

#  rough comparison
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark( fastPOSIXct( date , tz = "GMT" ) , as.POSIXct( date , format= "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M") , times = 100L )
#Unit: microseconds
#                                        expr     min      lq  median       uq     max neval
#               fastPOSIXct(date, tz = "GMT")  19.598  21.699  24.148  25.5485 215.927   100
# as.POSIXct(date, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M") 160.633 163.433 168.332 181.9800 278.220   100
```

But the question would be, is it quicker to transform your dates to a format `fasttime` can accept or just use `as.POSIXct` or buy a faster computer?!

Comment: Based on what I've seen (from your answer, and the answers/ comments in @BenBolker comments, it seems that there is no really simple solution. thanks for the fasttime tip. Buy a faster computer? Heh, it's already fast, I'm just try to keep an eye out for how to do things better on the programming side of things.