# Subsetting Data based on a date range in R

Tags: r, strptime

UPDATE

I've managed to load the data of the first 1000000 rows using the following code:

```
newFile <- read.table("course_4_proj_1.txt", header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings = "?", nrows= 1000000, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

This is what the `head()` returns, as an FYI

```
head(newFile)
        Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage Global_intensity
1 16/12/2006 17:24:00               4.216                 0.418  234.84             18.4
2 16/12/2006 17:25:00               5.360                 0.436  233.63             23.0
3 16/12/2006 17:26:00               5.374                 0.498  233.29             23.0
4 16/12/2006 17:27:00               5.388                 0.502  233.74             23.0
5 16/12/2006 17:28:00               3.666                 0.528  235.68             15.8
6 16/12/2006 17:29:00               3.520                 0.522  235.02             15.0
  Sub_metering_1 Sub_metering_2 Sub_metering_3
1              0              1             17
2              0              1             16
3              0              2             17
4              0              1             17
5              0              1             17
6              0              2             17
```

Now I need to subset because I only need to use the data from the dates 2007-02-01 and 2007-02-02. But I think I would need to convert the Date and Time variables to Date/Time classes in R using `strptime()` and `as.Date()` functions, but I'm not clear on how to do that. What is the simplest/cleanest way to do this?

Comment: It's best to ask just one question at at time. Especially when the question are so different.

Comment: You may want to preprocess the file with something like `grep`.

Comment: There is a way to do this... Provide first 5/10 records as file you mentioned is very large...

Comment: It sounds like one of your lines has a different number of fields. Perhaps you have incorrectly specified the delimiter? The function `counts.fields` can be helpful in tracking down which line is irregular.

Comment: I've pasted the first few rows using head() function in my original question above.

Comment: I used ":" instead of ";". I'll see if that was it.

Comment: It's not good form to completely change your question with an edit. If you have a new question, start a new thread rather than removing everything and asking something different.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to stack overflow and a novice R user. I'll go ahead and follow your recommendations.

Comment: @Jilber, thank you for the re-formatting...I'm learning!

Answer (score 3):

If size/memory is not an issue,

```
newFile <- read.table("course_4_proj_1.txt", header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings = "?", nrows= 1000000, 
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
newFile$DateTime <- paste(newFile$Date, newFile$Time), 
newFile$DateTime <- as.Date(newFile$DateTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

If your computer is too weak and puny, but you can add packages, consider the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
newFile <- fread("course_4_proj_1.txt", na.strings = "?")

newFile[,DateTime := as.Date(paste(Date, Time), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")]
```

and there are further optimizations one can use. I found [answers here useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218297/convert-string-date-to-r-date-fast-for-all-dates).

One can then subset the data.frame in the normal way. Here is a method using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
subsetted <- filter(newFile, DateTime >= as.Date("2006-02-01 00:00:00"), DateTime < as.Date("2006-02-03 00:00:00"))
```

Comment: This is an excellent summary and very useful. I've applied this script and it worked perfectly. Thank you, Hugh.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting stuck on the very last line of code you included above. It returns ZERO observations (i.e. rows). I've tried to reconstruct your code exactly and just not getting the correct result at the very end. Any idea what may be amiss?

Comment: Probably because you want dates between `2007-02-01` and `2007-02-02` instead of `2006`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The standard R `read.table` functions always read in the entire data set first. You might consider filtering the file some other way before reading into R, or using a package like `sqldf` which has a `read.csv.sql` function that can filter data on import. I haven't tested it with date classes yet.

Comment: So would I simply run read.table() to load the .txt file, and then subset the data I need? Is this the cleanest/simplest way? I definitely need simple over complicated as I am a novice R user.

Comment: @user3682294 That is the simplest (if you've got the RAM for it).

Comment: Once you have subset the data you can 'remove' the portion you do not want, so it is not using up computer resources.  See `?rm`

Comment: This is what I have that will only load the first 1,000,000 rows (the dates I need are safely within this range of rows): `code`newFile <- read.table("course_4_proj_1.txt", header=TRUE, sep=":", na.strings = "?", nrows= 1000000, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)