# Filter by column values while reading using read.csv in R

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset in the form of a txt file with values separated by semi colons and has close to 2M rows. I need data only corresponding to particular dates in the first col. Sample input is shown below:

```
Date;Time;Global_active_power;Global_reactive_power;Voltage;Global_intensity;Sub_metering_1;Sub_metering_2;Sub_metering_3
16/12/2006;17:24:00;4.216;0.418;234.840;18.400;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2006;17:25:00;5.360;0.436;233.630;23.000;0.000;1.000;16.000
16/12/2006;17:26:00;5.374;0.498;233.290;23.000;0.000;2.000;17.000
```

Please help me to filter data corresponding to two dates say 1/2/2007 and 2/2/2007

Comment: It is relatively easy to drop columns in a `read.csv` call through the col.classes argument. If your data is ordered by date, you could figure out the set of rows you want to read manually and then use the skip and nrows argument to read in those rows.

Comment: Maybe some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592219/read-csv-from-specific-row/6592373#6592373

Comment: Also, if this dataset gets close to eating up your available memory, you should take a look at `fread` in `data.table` or `read.csv.raw`/ `read.chunk` in `iotools`.

Comment: Pretty much the same question as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006475/subsetting-data-based-on-a-date-range-in-r/24006532#24006532

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a good answer on filtering during data import: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15967406/1152809

Basically, you need to use [sqldf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqldf/versions/0.4-7.1/topics/read.csv.sql) to filter during import. Here's something like what you need:

```
install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)
df <- read.csv.sql("sample.csv", "select *, from file where Date = '01/02/2007' or Date = '2/2/2007 ", sep=";")
```

However, I haven't tested this because you didn't give us a [dput](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dput.html) of your data. Take a look at this post for [info on how to do a good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on R.

Your dates are strings, so they can use the above. However, if you want to use date-specific functions like BETWEEN, you're going to need to change them to the correct format. Here's a sample:

```
df <- read.csv.sql("sample.csv", "select *, strftime('%d/%m/%Y', Date) as DateFormated from file where DateFormatted >= 1/2/2007 and DateFormatted <= 2/2/2007 ", sep=";")
```

Comment: Thank you Travis. It worked
input <- read.csv.sql("household_power_consumption.txt","select * from file where Date = '1/1/2007' or Date = '2/2/2007' ",sep=";")

Comment: What's with the comma after `select *`?