# Create a timestamp quickly in data.table from date and time columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set with 5 million plus rows and I would like to create a timestamp from two columns, one with a date and one with a time value.

When I read the csv into R using the fread() function, all columns are in character format, so I convert them into their relevant format using data.table, which is very fast for that kind of thing:

```
nf[, (dcols):= lapply(.SD,ymd),.SDcols=dcols] #using the ymd() function from lubridate to change date columns
```

My next step is to create a timestamp, which I do in the following way:

```
nf[,start_timestamp := as.POSIXct(paste(start_date,start_time))]
```

If I run Sys.Time() around this function call, I get a time difference of 3.843 minutes. This is a while to wait, so I was wondering if anyone could suggest a data.table based solution that will allow me to more quickly combine these two columns into a single timestamp?

Comment: You should make a reproducible example: some usable data as a function of `n` and `nc` (rows and columns), along with appropriate library calls. Data.table includes some date time functionality, but it involves keeping date and time in separate columns. See `?IDateTime`.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12898544/3001626). My guess is that `as.POSIXct` is your bottleneck. Also, I'm not sure what are you using `ymd` for.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think that `as.POSIXct` must be the bottleneck. I was using `ymd` to change the date format from character to date - I found it worked faster than `as.Date`. @Frank - I will create some example data and edit the original post.

Comment: Did you look at the link in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, just tried `fastPOSIXct` in the code example above and it completed across the whole data set in 26 seconds. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Don't do that `tt2 <- tt2` thingi please. `:=` updates `tt2` *in place*. Also, instead of `tt2 <- as.data.table(tt)`, just do `setDT(tt)` and operate on `tt`. No need to have identical copies of the same data sets in the environment.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @DavidArenburg - I'm not so familiar with the data.table syntax (I mostly work with dplyr), so it's much appreciated. The copy was just a leftover from my testing the solutions in RStudio and not wanting to reload the data every time something went wrong.

Comment: Hi, I'm rolling back your edit for two reasons. You didn't actually provide sample data there. Also, you should keep the answer in the answer section instead of posting it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create time stamps much more quickly by using the `fastPOSIXct` function from the `fasttime` package

[Sample data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-PaxTw3xOPZZHNxUkRtSVNVMms)

```
library(data.table)
library(fasttime)
library(lubridate)

ttfile <- "timestamp_test_data.csv"

tt <- read.table(ttfile, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep=",",na.strings=c("NA","N/A","null"))

dcols <- c('start_date','end_date')
tcols <- c('start_time','end_time')

setDT(tt) #convert to data.table

tt[, (dcols):= lapply(.SD,mdy),.SDcols=dcols] # := updates the data table in place, no need to pass it to another vector
tt[, (tcols):= lapply(.SD,as.ITime),.SDcols=tcols]

tt[,start_timestamp := fastPOSIXct(paste(start_date,start_time - 3600))] #remove number of seconds in an hour to fix fastPOSIXct adding an hour to the timestamp - if it doesn't do that for you, just remove that part
tt[,end_timestamp := fastPOSIXct(paste(end_date,end_time - 3600))]

str(tt)
```