# cast string directly to IDateTime

Tags: r, datetime, data.table

I am using the new version of `data.table` and especially the AWESOME `fread` function. My files contain dates that are loaded as strings (cause I don't know to do it otherwise) looking like `01APR2008:09:00:00`.

I need to sort the data.table on those datetimes and then for the sort to be efficient to cast then in the `IDateTime` format (or anything alse I would not know yet).

```
> strptime("01APR2008:09:00:00","%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
[1] "2008-04-01 09:00:00"

> IDateTime(strptime("01APR2008:09:00:00","%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"))
        idate    itime
1: 2008-04-01 09:00:00

> IDateTime("01APR2008:09:00:00","%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

It looks like I cannot do `DT[ , newType := IDateTime(strptime(oldType, "%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"))]`.

My questions are then:

1. Is there a way to cast directly to `IDateTime` from `fread`, such that I can sort afterward efficiently?
2. If not, what is the most efficient way to go knowing that I would like to be able to sort DT by this datetime column

Comment: can you show how they look your data files?

Comment: hello, the file is a csv file with `sep=";"` and the date format looks like `"01APR2008:09:00:00"` which is `format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"`.
What I did is `DT[,date:=IDate(oldType,"%d%b%Y")];DT[,time:=ITime(oldType,"%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")]` and finally `setkeyv(DT,c("date","time"))`

Comment: the date is the first column of your data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately (for efficiency) `strptime` produces a POSIXlt type, which is unsupported by `data.table` and always will be due its size (40 bytes per date!) and structure. Although `strftime` produces the much better POSIXct, it still does it via POSIXlt. More info here :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12788992/403310
```

Looking to base functions such as `as.Date`, it uses `strptime` too, creating an integer offset from epoch (oddly) stored as double. The `IDate` (and friends) class in `data.table` aims to achieve integer epoch offsets stored as, um, integer. Suitable for fast sorting by `base::sort.list(method = "radix")` (which is really a counting sort). `IDate` doesn't really aim to be fast at (usually one off) conversion.

So to convert string dates/times, rightly or wrongly, I tend to roll my own helper function.

If the string date is `"2012-12-24"` I'd lean towards: `as.integer(gsub("-", "", col))` and proceed with `YYYYMMDD` integer dates. Similarly times can be `HHMMDD` as an integer. Two columns: `date` and `time` separately can be useful if you generally want to `roll = TRUE` within a day, but not to the previous day. Grouping by month is simple and fast: `by = date %/% 100L`. Adding and subtracting days is troublesome, but it is anyway because rarely do you want to add calendar days, rather weekdays or business days. So that's a lookup to your business day vector anyway.

In your case the character month would need a conversion to `1:12`. There isn't a separator in your dates "01APR2008", so a `substring` would be one way followed by a `match` or `fmatch` on the month name. Are you in control of the file format? If so, numbers are better in an unambiguous format that sorts naturally such as `%Y-%m-%d`, or `%Y%m%d`.

I haven't yet got to how best do this in `fread`, so date/times are left as character currently because I'm not yet sure how to detect the date format or which type to output. It does need to output either integer or double dates though, rather than inefficient character. I suspect that my use of `YYYYMMDD` integers are seen as unconventional, so I'm a little hesitant to make that the default. They have their place, and there are pros and cons of epoch based dates too. Dates don't *have* to be always epoch based is all I'm suggesting.

What do you think? Btw, thanks for encouragement on `fread`; was nice to see.

Comment: Hey Matthew thanks for answering, one possibility would be I guess to allow a colClasses argument like in read.csv. After all you can indicate your own format like in (pardon the exemple I taken from another post) 
`R) setAs("character","myDate", function(from) as.Date(from, format="%d/%m/%y") )`

`R) system.time(data <- read.csv(file=filePath, sep=";", stringsAsFactors=TRUE, colClasses=c("factor","factor","numeric","myDate"), nrows=10));`

Comment: Additionally I think you would touch a lot more guy if you could add microsecond resolution time in the package. All HFTraders/quants are playing with this stuff... (arguably they should not use R for this but let's not go there)

Comment: Agreed, `colClasses` is already on the list to add (TO DO list is at the top of fread.c), but as a named vector allowing to override particular columns rather than needing to specify them all. It was more a question about the default really. I suppose `POSIXct`, then. That supports microseconds already so I don't see that as anything special `data.table` needs to support really, iiuc (other than fread could load them up directly and quickly). The main reason I wanted to do fread was for dual delimited files (sep2), though, such as in genomics.

Answer (score 1):

I d'ont know how your file is structured, but from your comment you want to use the date field as a key. Why not to read it as a time series and format it when in reading?

Here I use zoo to do it.(Here I suppose that the date column is the first one,otherwise see `index.colum` argument)

```
ff <- function(x) as.POSIXct(strptime(x,"%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S"))

h <- read.zoo(text = "03avril2008:09:00:00  125
                      02avril2008:09:30:00  126
                      05avril2008:09:10:00  127
                      04avril2008:09:20:00  128
                      01avril2008:09:00:00  128"
                      ,FUN=ff)
```

You get your dates sorted in the right format and sorted.

The conversion is natural from POSIXct to IDateTime

```
    IDateTime(index(h))
        idate    itime
1: 2008-04-01 09:00:00
2: 2008-04-02 09:30:00
3: 2008-04-03 09:00:00
4: 2008-04-04 09:20:00
5: 2008-04-05 09:10:00
```

Here sure you still do 2 conversions, But you do it when reading data, and the second you do it without dealing with any format problem.