# Working With Years in a Monthly POSIX data set

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts

I working with monthly climate data from several weather stations across the Greater Albuquerque Area, I have taken this subset for the airport data as an example, I will eventually apply this same process to all locations. There are close to 500 months of data available but I have included the first 30 here.

```
> head(ABQ, 30)
                                STATION_NAME       DATE CLDD
9698 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1945-05-01  449
9699 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1945-06-01 1335
9700 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1945-07-01 2330
9701 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1945-08-01 2269
9702 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1945-09-01 1247
9703 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1945-10-01   13
9709 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1946-04-01   62
9710 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1946-05-01  251
9711 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1946-06-01 2097
9712 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1946-07-01 2303
9713 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1946-08-01 1889
9714 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1946-09-01 1111
9715 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1946-10-01   23
9721 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1947-04-01    1
9722 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1947-05-01  611
9723 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1947-06-01 1273
9724 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1947-07-01 2636
9725 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1947-08-01 1892
9726 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1947-09-01 1265
9727 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1947-10-01  171
9733 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1948-04-01   91
9734 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1948-05-01  642
9735 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1948-06-01 1506
9736 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1948-07-01 2529
9737 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1948-08-01 2186
9738 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1948-09-01 1130
9739 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1948-10-01   13
9745 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1949-04-01   88
9746 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1949-05-01  304
9747 ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US 1949-06-01 1477
```

I would like to call the yearly sum of ABQ$CLDD and apply that value to a ggplot()... something like this

```
    CLDD_yr <- apply.yearly(ABQ$DATE, sum(CLDD))
    p <- ggplot(CLDD_yr, aes(YEAR, CLDD_yr)),
         + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x + I(x^2), size = 1)
```

I know I am making a mistake somewhere in calling the data I think but I can not seem to sort this out.

The DATE column is POSIX time as seen here

```
> class(ABQ$DATE)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

EDIT:
per coffienjunkies comments

perhaps a new df would be the best way to approach this as I will need to look at data for more than one location in the same manner

```
> stations
      unique(Bernalillo_data$STATION_NAME)
1  ALBUQUERQUE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT NM US
2            PETROGLYPH NATIONAL MON NM US
3                        SANDIA PARK NM US
4                    ALBUQUERQUE VLY NM US
5           ALBUQUERQUE FOOTHILLS NE NM US
6              SANDIA RANGER STATION NM US
7                       SANDIA CREST NM US
8                 LA MADERA SKI AREA NM US
9                    NETHERWOOD PARK NM US
10                   EXPERIMENT FARM NM US
11                      KIRTLAND AFB NM US
```

maybe the new DF should be something like

```
header <-  station_name    Year    CLDD_sum
```

this would make the analysis simpler I think in the long run.

Comment: Why the reluctance to create a dataframe summarizing the values? One way or another, some aggregation will have to occur at some point.

Comment: @coffeinjunky, I would like to be able to keep referencing the same data throughout my script for readability. it will be seen by other people... I am not completely opposed to it I guess, I just want the code to do the work so to speak

Comment: Would creating new columns be an option?

Comment: Sure, but this would lead to a 'melt' scenario right? I would probably be better off just making a new df... perhaps you can pose that answer.. I think it would still be relevant, how do I sum yearly values as a call from YYYY-MM-DD posix times?

Comment: `new.df <- aggregate(data = ABQ, CLDD ~ DATE$year, sum)`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns, Thanks. that is nice... what would the analog be for a df that had multiple stations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are many approaches you could use, but some aggregation will have to occur at some point. Here are two suggestions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df$year <- df$DATE$year
df$DATE <- as.POSIXct(df$DATE) # dplyr doesn't play well with POSIXlt
df_yr <- df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(cldd_yr = sum(CLDD))
```

This yields:

```
Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

   year cldd_yr
  (chr)   (int)
1  1945    7643
2  1946    7736
3  1947    7849
4  1948    8097
5  1949    1869
```

which you can use in combination with `ggplot`. For multiple stations, just add the station as grouping variable. For instance, `df_yr <- df %>% group_by(year, station) %>% summarise(cldd_yr = sum(CLDD))` will give you the summary for all years and stations, provided that `station` is how your identifier is called.

If you really don't want to use a new dataframe but are ok with adding a column, try

```
 df <- group_by(df, year) %>% mutate(yr.sum = sum(CLDD))
```

In `yr.sum`, you have the yearly sum. Note that this value is repeating, and you will have to make sure that `ggplot` uses it correctly. I would propose to use the first approach though, as it is probably more efficient and more transparent.

Comment: sure thing.. but i have a question regarding your df$DATE$year... this part is giving me an error 'object of type closure is not subsettable' I can see how your answer will work out to what I need so I selected it, and I am sure I can get there but I was not expecting this

Comment: one note though.. the     > df_yr <- df %>% group_by(year, station) %>% summarise(CLDD_yr = sum(CLDD))
Error: column 'DATE' has unsupported type : POSIXlt, POSIXt

Comment: > library(dplyr)
> library(ggplot2) > df <- Bernalillo_data
> df$year <- df$DATE$year
> df_yr <- df %>% group_by(year,STATION_NAME) %>% summarise(CLDD_yr = sum(CLDD))
Error: column 'DATE' has unsupported type : POSIXlt, POSIXt

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828850/dplyr-does-not-group-data-by-date for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
require(data.table)
setDT(ABQ)
ABQ[, CLDD_yr := sum(CLDD), by = year(DATE)]

# Required because data.table and ggplot don't play nice.
setDF(ABQ)


p <- ggplot(ABQ, aes(YEAR, CLDD_yr)),
  + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x + I(x^2), size = 1)
```

note that you will have to install `data.table`. Note that this will create your summary statistic for every row so you might get several dots overlapping in ggplot. If you do not want that you could try,

```
require(data.table)
setDT(ABQ)
for_plot <- ABQ[, .(CLDD_yr := sum(CLDD)), by = list(year = year(DATE))]

# Required because data.table and ggplot don't play nice.
setDF(for_plot)


p <- ggplot(for_plot, aes(year, CLDD_yr)),
  + stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y~x + I(x^2), size = 1)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is a good solution.. I am trying to be minimize new packages but this does work. thank you

Comment: For convenience you will probably have to use `data.table` or `dplyr`. I prefer the former for performance reasons and it works well with `xts` objects.