# Data.table size increases manifolds after performing operation on column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table `score` of size 900Mb. There is a column `datetime` which is essentially a datetime in the format `("2018-05-25 10:10:53:000000")`. I am trying to convert the class `character` of this particular column to `POSIXlt` using the following code:

```
score[,newdate := as.POSIXlt.character(score[["datetime"]],tz="IST",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")][,datetime:=NULL]
```

This operation renders a data.table of size 211 GB. What is happening here. Please help.

```
dput(head(score))

structure(list(id1 = c(12234398L, 323437283L, 12343344L, 
545465653L, 312342343L, 22344232L), id2 = c(216231535L, 
324345453L, 345474698L, 87787950L, 656565531L, 565656657L), 
Score = c(756L, 777L, 788L, 234L, 656L, 788L), datetime = c("2017-05-08 00:00:00.0000000", 
"2018-07-12 01:24:46.0000000", "2015-16-02 00:00:00.0000000", 
"2016-03-22 23:06:45.0000000", "2016-07-14 12:23:45.0000000", 
"2014-05-03 03:33:13.0000000")), .Names = c("id1", 
"id2", "Score", "datetime"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x190cc98>)
```

Comment: Are you not getting any warning for `tz="IST"`?

Comment: @MKR No. Why do you think it should throw a warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487614/error-creating-r-data-table-with-date-time-posixlt?noredirect=1&lq=1 I think this might be your issue.

Comment: @TUSHAR I think problem is use of `score[["datetime"]]`. Its creating selfreference. Why cant you use `datetime` instead?

Comment: @MKR Its not the issue, its the `POSIXlt` format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487614/error-creating-r-data-table-with-date-time-posixlt?noredirect=1&lq=1)

`data.table` doesn't accept `POSIXlt` columns. You can use `POSIXct` instead of `POSIXlt`.

```
score[, newdate := as.POSIXct(datetime, tz = "IST", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")][, datetime := NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works great. It in fact led to decrease in the size of the data.table.

Answer (score 1):

To explain, why the `data.table` is growing so much:

```
d <- as.POSIXlt.character("2017-05-08 00:00:00.0000000", ,tz="IST",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d
object.size(d) # 2024 Bytes in my configuration
# 2024 bytes
```

`?POSIXlt` says that

> Class "POSIXlt" is a named list of vectors representing...

This means that every single `POSIXlt` object consist of many elements represeting the components of a date and time.

This costs a lot of memory (can't remember, but about 80 bytes per POSIXlt element + overhead for the vector structure).

The assignment operator of `data.table` has a special handling of list (each list element is assigned to a different column) so you get a warning with your code snippet like:

> Warning message:
>       In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(newdate, as.POSIXlt.character(data[["datetime"]],  :
>         Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 6 items of column 'newdate' (5 unused)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I read somewhere in one of the links that @zacdav shared that each POSIXlt element takes around 40 bytes of memory.