# Vector of dates inconsistent length after rounding in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I need both the original and a rounded-to-the-day version of a datetime in a data.table. When I use the base round function to do this (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325631/round-a-posix-date-posixct-with-base-r-functionality)), I start getting errors regarding the number of items when I try to add it back into my data.table - even though the length looks right.

Example:

```
temp <- data.table(ID=1:3,dates_unrounded=rep(as.POSIXct(NA),3),dates_rounded=rep(as.POSIXct(NA),3))
dates_form1 <- c("2021-04-01","2021-06-30","2021-05-22")
dates_form2 <- as.POSIXct(dates_form1,format="%Y-%m-%d")
temp$dates_unrounded <- dates_form2
dates_form3 <- round(dates_form2,"days")
temp$dates_rounded <- dates_form3
length(dates_form3)
length(temp$dates_unrounded)
```

When run, produces:

```
> temp <- data.table(ID=1:3,dates_unrounded=rep(as.POSIXct(NA),3),dates_rounded=rep(as.POSIXct(NA),3))
> dates_form1 <- c("2021-04-01","2021-06-30","2021-05-22")
> dates_form2 <- as.POSIXct(dates_form1,format="%Y-%m-%d")
> temp$dates_unrounded <- dates_form2
> dates_form3 <- round(dates_form2,"days")
> temp$dates_rounded <- dates_form3
Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 3 items of column 'dates_rounded'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
> length(dates_form3)
[1] 3
> length(temp$dates_unrounded)
[1] 3
```

What's going wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Looks like a `data.table` thing. If you do `temp <- as.data.frame(temp)` and run your code, it works fine. Indeed: (a) `class(dates_form3)` reveals that `round()` has returned a POSIXlt object, and this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67286833/vector-of-dates-inconsistent-length-after-rounding-in-r) reveals that data.table doesn't like POSIXlt. Use `as.POSIXct` on `dates_form3` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?round.POSIXt` reveals that in this case, `round()` returns a POSIXlt object. But data.table [doesn't work with those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487614/error-creating-r-data-table-with-date-time-posixlt). So just do

```r
dates_form3 <- round(dates_form2,"days")
dates_form3 <- as.POSIXct(dates_form3)
temp$dates_rounded <- dates_form3
length(dates_form3)
length(temp$dates_unrounded)
```

and you're fine.