# R data table recommended way to deal with date time

Tags: r, datetime, data.table

I have a csv file with one column of timestamps "2000-01-01 12:00:00.123456". What's the recommended way to dealing with it in data table? I need to deal with grouping, matching/rolling join with IDate column from another table, time series plotting, etc.

```
IDateTime("2000-01-01 12:00:00.123456")

Error in if (any(neg)) res[neg] = paste("-", res[neg], sep = "") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I see this answer in the possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063077/1568919) question in which Matthew suggested manually casting dates into integers. But that's 3 years old and I wonder if there now exists a better way?

Comment: You need to pass it a `POSIXct` object, Try `IDateTime(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 12:00:00.123456"))`. You may need to specify time zone via the `tz` argument for special cases.

Comment: Thanks. Could you put that into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IDateTime` requires a `POSIXct` class object in order to work properly (it seems to work properly with a `factor` conversion too, not sure why). I agree it isn't documented very well and maybe worth opening an FR/PR on GH regarding documentation- there is an open queue regarding an `IDateTime` [vignette](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944) though. And there is already an [FR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1383) regarding allowing it to work with a `character` class.

```
IDateTime(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 12:00:00.123456"))
#         idate    itime
# 1: 2000-01-01 12:00:00
## IDateTime(factor("2000-01-01 12:00:00.123456")) ## will also work
```

Pay attention to the `tz` parameter in `as.POSIXct` if you want to avoid unexpected behaviour

---

Regardless, it seems like the error is actually caused by the print method of `ITime` which calls `format.ITime`, see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/IDateTime.R#L89) and [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/IDateTime.R#L89)
e.g., if you will run `res <- IDateTime("2015-09-29 08:22:00")` this will *not* produce an error, though `res` will be `NA` due to wrong conversion (I believe) in [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/IDateTime.R#L59-L68) (the format is only `"%H:%M:%OS"`). It seems like a bug to me and I still uncertain why `factor` class works correctly when there is no `factor` method in `methods(as.ITime)`. Maybe due to its `integer` internal storage mode which calls another related method.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the precision required for your time fields you may need to use `POSIXct` instead of `IDateTime`.
The timestamp format stored in your source file can be reproduced in R by `format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")`.
When using `IDateTime` you will lose the subseconds, you can play with `ITime` and see if it fits your need.
If you will stick to `POSIXct`then you should be aware of `?setNumericRounding` function which may be sometimes important as it affects ordering and joining on `POSIXct`'s underlying numeric data type.