# How should I use the as.POSIXlt function within a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, posixct, posixlt

In R, I'm trying to convert a POSIXct variable to a POSIXlt variable within a data table.
For some reason this fails, though other type-conversion functions work.

```
library(data.table)
# make a sequence of dates
start_date <- as.POSIXct(strptime("01/01/2016", "%d/%m/%Y"), tz = "UTC")
end_date   <- as.POSIXct(strptime("10/01/2016", "%d/%m/%Y"), tz = "UTC")
n_times <- 10  # number of time points
datect <- seq(start_date, end_date, length = n_times)
datect

# put these in a data frame
df <- data.frame(datect = datect)
# and a data table
dt <- as.data.table(df)
```

Converting this to POSIXlt works fine within a data frame:

```
df$datelt <- as.POSIXlt(df$datect)
```

but fails in a data table:

```
dt$datelt <- as.POSIXlt(dt$datect)

Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'datelt'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Other functions work ok, such as converting to a character or

```
dt$datech <- as.character(dt$datect)
dt$datech <- as.numeric(dt$datect)
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: This is because `data.table` doesn't support `POSIXlt`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063077/13513328