# Efficiently formatting date and time in large data sets in R - dplyr performance

Tags: r, performance, datetime, dplyr, large-data

This question is on code performance. I have a data frame with two columns:

- `DATE` is represented as numeric in `MMDDYYYY` format
- `EPOCH` is a representation of time in 5 minute increments from midnight. `EPOCH` count starts at 0 - so 00:00 to 00:05 would be 0, 00:05 to 00:10 would be 1 and so on.

I have about 15 million rows of data in my data frame. As a part of processing this data I am converting the two columns to R's `Date` and `POSIXct` format. I am using `dplyr` - however, the code I have is taking way too long (about 30 minutes). Below I am generating a toy data set and provided the code I am using:

```
library(dplyr)
DATA <- data.frame(DATE = rep(10082013,15000000), EPOCH = rep(6,15000000))
```

Here is a sample view of the data

```
DATA %>% 
  head()

     DATE EPOCH
1 10082013     6
2 10082013     6
3 10082013     6
4 10082013     6
5 10082013     6
6 10082013     6
```

This is the part where I transform the data into the format I want it in:

```
DATA %>%
  mutate(DATE_FORMATTED = as.Date(as.character(DATE), "%m%d%Y")) %>%
  mutate(DOW = weekdays(DATE_FORMATTED)) %>%
  mutate(TIME_FORMATTED = strftime(as.POSIXct(((EPOCH+1)*5*60), origin=as.character(DATE_FORMATTED), tz="UTC"), format="%R", tz="UTC")) %>%
  head()
```

I feel the overhead is due to all the coercions in the `TIME_FORMATTED` formula. Is there a way to achieve the end result faster? Maybe a different function that is `dplyr` optimized?

Comment: Why are you coercing `DATE_FORMATTED` back to `character` in the last `mutate`? According to the docs, `origin` gets coerced to `Date` anyway.

Comment: Yes - the character coercion of origin in last mutate statement was indeed redundant.

Comment: Ok - I see why I was using that. I was getting confused between the two functions `strptime` and `strftime`. The former requires coercion while the latter does not. However, the code is still slow. :(

Comment: We currently don't have any optimised dplyr functions for date times, but it's on my radar

Comment: @hadley: Is there a documentation that lists the functions that are optimized for `mutate`?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in ["Why is as.Date slow on a character vector?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12786335/2954547), the bottleneck is probably `strptime`. In particular, the answer by user daniel.s suggests using `lubridate::fast_strptime`.

And there's no need to convert `DATE_FORMATTED` to `character`.

Mind you, I haven't done any testing myself so maybe a better answer will come along.