# RODBC posixct date field makes query very slow

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc, rjdbc

I need help with RODBC `sqlQuery`. I run a SQL script that produces 11mill rows of data. It takes 78 secs to pull data using RODBC but unfortunately when I include a date/time field, it takes 180 secs to pull data from RODBC and only 78 secs in Management Studio. I would like to find out why please and what I could do about it.

The date/time field is of this format on Sql server: *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000*

I make sure I do `Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")`before I run this query:

```r
lossdata <- as.data.table(sqlQuery(dbhandle, qry))
```

*qry* is a string and *dbhandle* is set using `odbcDriverConnect`.

I get the date/time field in this format when I pull from R: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (without .000)`

I've tried RJDBC too but it takes same time. It also takes too long to convert the date/time field from character to `posixct` after using RJDBC so it's not a good option. Unfortunately I need the field to be in `posixct` as I use it in sorting and it takes too long if it is not of this data type.

Please help. I'm not sure how I can reproduce this example. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

**SQL Queries**

With *EventDate*

```sql
select pp.EventDate as EVENTDATE, pp.EVENTID as EVENTID 
from 
    (select * from set.dbo.events where setid in (16,32)) pp 
     inner join 
        (select eventid from databasename.dbo.rdm_port where anls = 93) y 
     on pp.EventId = y.EVENTID
```

Without *EventDate*

```sql
select pp.EVENTID as EVENTID 
from 
   (select * from set.dbo.events where setid in (16,32)) pp 
    inner join 
       (select eventid from databasename.dbo.rdm_port where anls = 93) y 
    on pp.EventId = y.EVENTID
```

Comment: Please show query that includes the datetime and one that does not to see how calculations are being run.

Comment: i have made the script smaller to make it readable, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Perhaps RODBC is converting your DateTime column from a character to a Date using the function `as.Date`, which is very slow. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12788992/6004997 for details: "So the crux of the issue (I think) is why strptime is so slow, and maybe that can be improved in R. Or just avoid POSIXlt, either directly or indirectly."

Comment: hi corey thanks for taking the time to reply. i ran the query with as.is = TRUE and it ran 2x faster...

Comment: unfortunately i need to preserve the data/time timestamp. i use it to sort later and it turns out very slow if it is not in the right format.

Comment: any particular reason why the .000 would be truncated? do you think that's causing it difficulties?

Comment: @charliealpha - please delete your above query comments which you should have edited in your own post as comments are difficult to read. I added it accordingly. Do note: you are allowed to edit your question at *any* time.

Comment: thank you for your time, apologies still kinda new to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',pp.EventDate) as EVENTDATE
```

And using RJDBC instead solves this particular problem.

RODBC takes longer than RJDBC. Everything is stored as numeric using RJDBC.

The date is now in seconds since 1970-01-01 which is fast to sort. It can be converted to date if need be.