# How to vectorise fast_strptime for quick datetimes using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I am using data.table as i am dealing with >5 million observations per csv file, however i am having some trouble converting my character vector of dates into datetime objects so that i can aggregate the data.

Note, my data is in format "20120127154843" however in the sample dataset i supply the format is "2012-01-27 15:48:43" (this may influence whether fastPOSIXct() can be used).

I tried to convert the lt format object created by fast_strptime to vector format as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24148520/7778675 however it does not seem to speed things up dramatically and the largest time cost is in the conversion.

Surprisingly the function `ymd_hms()` works quite well (but not as quick as `fast_strptime()`).

Any advice on how to combine `fast_strptime()` and `data.table()` are very welcome!

```
# Load packages
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(fasttime)

# Set up data
dt <- as.data.table(rep(as.character(Sys.time()+runif(1,-1e9,1e9)),5e6))

# Determine time stamp
# as.POSIXct
system.time(dt[ , starttime := as.POSIXct(V1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam")])
# fast_strptime and as.POSIXct
system.time(dt[ , starttime := as.POSIXct(fast_strptime(V1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam"))])
# fast_strptime
system.time(starttime <-  fast_strptime(dt[, V1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam"))
# fast_strptime convert lt to ct format
system.time(starttime <-  fast_strptime(dt[, V1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam", lt = F))
# parse_date_time2
system.time(dt[ , starttime := parse_date_time2(V1, orders = "YmdHMS", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam")])
# ymd_hms
system.time(dt[ , starttime := ymd_hms(V1, tz = "Europe/Amsterdam")])
```

The results are as follows:

```
> # Determine time stamp
> # as.POSIXct
> system.time(dt[ , starttime := as.POSIXct(V1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam")])
   user  system elapsed 
  49.65    0.06   49.75 
> # fast_strptime and as.POSIXct
> system.time(dt[ , starttime := as.POSIXct(fast_strptime(V1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam"))])
   user  system elapsed 
  25.06    0.05   25.16 
> # fast_strptime
> system.time(starttime <-  fast_strptime(dt[, V1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam"))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.33    0.06    0.39 
> # fast_strptime convert lt to ct format
> system.time(starttime <-  fast_strptime(dt[, V1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam", lt = F))
   user  system elapsed 
  24.48    0.05   24.56 
> # parse_date_time2
> system.time(dt[ , starttime := parse_date_time2(V1, orders = "YmdHMS", tz = "Europe/Amsterdam")])
   user  system elapsed 
  24.55    0.06   24.62 
> # ymd_hms
> system.time(dt[ , starttime := ymd_hms(V1, tz = "Europe/Amsterdam")])
   user  system elapsed 
   1.36    0.12    1.53
```

Comment: are all (or a large %) of the timestamps likely to be unique?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, most timestamps are unique

Comment: how many csv files do you have? 0.39s seems fast to me. and if the datetime is so disparate, u are still going to get a lot of rows after aggregation defeating its purpose

Comment: @chinsoon12 I have around 100 csv files, all approximately 5 million observations, so i am trying to cut down the number of time it takes to convert a string into a datetime from > 30 sec to around 1 second (ideally).

Comment: Maybe it would help to rbindlist first before applying the function

Comment: @chinsoon12, instead of as.POSIXct? I dont fully understand...